# SupportsCertificate throws no mutually supported protocol versions for x509Certificate extracted from pfx

Tags: go, ssl, post, x509certificate

With the following code, I'm creating a TLS cert

```
func loadCert() tls.Certificate {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to find / open cert file", err)
    }
    p, c, err1 := pkcs12.Decode(b, password)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to read cert content", err1)
    }
    tlsCert := tls.Certificate{
        PrivateKey: p,
        Leaf:       c,
    }
    return tlsCert
}
```

And then with NewCertPool(), I am adding this to the pool

```
func makeRequest(){    
    // Loading cert
    cert := loadCert()
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()

    caCertPool.AddCert(cert.Leaf)

    tConfig := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: caCertPool,
        PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
        InsecureSkipVerify:       false,
        Certificates:             []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    tr := &http.Transport{
      TLSClientConfig: tConfig,
    }

    client := http.Client{
        Transport: tr,
    }
    request, reqError := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(dataToPost))
    if reqError != nil {
         log.Fatalln(" failed with error", reqError)
    }
    request.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
    request.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
    res, dErr := client.Do(request)
    if dErr != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to make request", dErr)
    } else {
        log.Println(res.StatusCode)
    }
}
```

SupportCertificate throws

> no mutually supported protocol versions

Same certificate works just fine with tools like Postman. If I remove the check with this supportCertificate function and try to make POST call server reports that client certificate is not found, despite adding it in the transport above . And on the client side I get the error that connection has been reset and

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

To remedy this I tried using SystemCertPool(), after which code fails to execute on windows with error SystemCertPool not found. On Docker or on VM it fails with

> connection has been reset by peer

I'm really at loss here what I am missing, would appreciate some help on this.

I have already scoured through really helpful posts on how TLS can be configured and how CA certs could be added to the new pool. But I still seem to be missing something.

Comment: `ClientHelloInfo.SupportsCertificate` needs to be called on a `ClientHelloInfo` during or after the TLS handshake. You're calling it on an uninitialized object. Remove this and show the part of the code that performs the actual POST. For the CA pool, the system cert pool does not work on windows, but there are workaround out there (you'll need to search for them)

Comment: You also shouldn't be adding your own client certificate to the pool, you need the CA that can verify the server certificate (either in the system pool, or a custom one you specify). You also don't need to set `ClientAuth`, that's a server-side setting.

Comment: @Marc i have edited my question with code for POST request. As you mentioned i have removed the ClientHello and cert from the pool. I can live with this not working on Windows, that is not my primary platform. So i have switched it to SystemCertPool and re-executing it on VM (Ubuntu 18) throws 
> read tcp <localIP>:port -> <serverIP>:<port> : read: connection reset by peer

Comment: What does the server side say?

Comment: @Marc i don't have access to the server, it's an external provider's server. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use your `http.Client` with configured `tls.Config`, where you re-defined Root CA. For example:

```
http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            RootCAs: caPool,
        },
},
```

where `caPool` can be obtained as

```
caPool, err := x509.SystemCertPool()
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("SystemCertPool() error: %v", err)
}
if caPool == nil {
    caPool = x509.NewCertPool()
}

certs, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read CA from file '%q': %v", path, err)
}

if ok := caPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs); !ok {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to append local CA to root cert pool")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this looks almost the same as what I am doing. The only difference I see that you check for SystemCertPool being null or not. It obviously doesn't work on windows, but my tests on docker (alpine image) & ubuntu 18 VM do not return null system pool.